# Get bytesUsed for volumes in a SoftLayer account

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to find out the amount of space used by the volumes for an account. I am using SoftLayer_Account::getIscsiNetworkStorage with object mask as *bytesUsed*.

```
objectMask = 'mask[bytesUsed]'
bytesUsed = client['Account'].getIscsiNetworkStorage(mask=objectMask)
```

My reference link is :
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/

I am getting a result set that contains username, capacityGb, nasType etc. however there is no information on the bytes used.

```
{'username': 'IBM01SELxxxxxx-1', 'capacityGb': 40, 'hostId': '', 'serviceProviderId': 1, 'nasType': 'ISCSI', 'upgradableFlag': True, 'storageTypeId': '7', 'createDate': '2017-12-14T19:06:23-06:00', 'serviceResourceName': 'PerfStor Aggr aggr_staasams0101_hp02', 'hardwareId': '', 'notes': 'Some Resources', 'billingItem': {'modifyDate': '2018-06-01T01:09:17-06:00', 'recurringMonths': 1, 'id': 891913, 'setupFee': '0', 'recurringFee': '0', 'lastBillDate': '2018-06-01T01:09:17-06:00', 'nextBillDate': '2018-06-30T23:00:00-06:00', 'createDate': '2017-12-14T19:05:57-06:00', 'oneTimeFeeTaxRate': '0', 'laborFeeTaxRate': '0', 'location': {'statusId': 2, 'id': 29892, 'name': 'iok01', 'longName': 'Something 1'}, 'parentId': '', 'cancellationDate': '', 'cycleStartDate': '2018-06-01T01:09:17-06:00', 'description': 'Storage as a Service', 'laborFee': '0', 'oneTimeFee': '0', 'setupFeeTaxRate': '0', 'categoryCode': 'storage_as_a_service', 'allowCancellationFlag': 1, 'serviceProviderId': 1, 'orderItemId': 27763, 'recurringFeeTaxRate': '0'}, 'guestId': '', 'serviceResource': {'attributes': [{'attributeType': {'keyname': 'VERSION'}, 'value': '1'}], 'type': {'type': 'NETAPP_STOR_AGGR'}, 'backendIpAddress': 'xxxxxxxxx-io.service.softlayer.com', 'name': 'Ouuty Aggr aggr_hsnsxxx_uik02', 'id': 7860}, 'id': 000008, 'accountId': 786xxx}
```

How must I define the mask so that I get the data for this particular relational property (bytesUsed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the bytesUsed property is  available only for File Storage, that's why it does not return any information about the amount of space used.